# Asp.Net Web Forms url is dropping the extension in the browser, causing 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

In Visual Studio, when we run the application and browse to http://localhost:1234/page.aspx, the page appears and everything works perfectly.

When we deploy this site to another server, and browse to http://[servername]/page.aspx, the browser drops the .aspx, so it looks like http://[servername]/page and we get a 404.

There is no MVC in play here.

Details:
c# 4.6.1 asp.net web forms application
IIS 6 on W2008

Comment: http://localhost means your local, if you deployed your site on an iis server it is suposed to be available via interenet

Comment: Can you look in the network tab in the browser tools and see if there are any redirects occurring

Comment: @stilgar the network tab is showing a 301 and then attempting to find the extensionless address with a 404

Comment: @AntoinePelletier updated the question to clarify the address. We are actually remoted locally onto the deployment machine.

Comment: Maybe there is an HTTP Module installed on the server to remove the extension?

Comment: @stilgar That's what we are looking at now. However, it deploys fine on W2012 servers (which was our end game anyway), so I think we are good. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond to me on this.